# How to efficiently add rows for those data points which are missing from a sequence using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following time series dataset of the number of sales happening for a day as a pandas data frame.

```
date, sales
20161224,5
20161225,2
20161227,4
20161231,8
```

Now if I have to include the missing data points here(i. e. missing dates) with a constant value(zero) and want to make it look the following way, how can I do this efficiently(assuming the data frame is ~50MB) using Pandas.

```
date, sales
20161224,5
20161225,2
20161226,0**
20161227,4
20161228,0**
20161229,0**
20161231,8
```

**Missing rows which are been added to the data frame.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first cast to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) column `date`, then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by min and max value of `index`, [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and if necessary change format by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d')
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()), fill_value=0)
      .reset_index()
      .rename(columns={'index':'date'})
print (df)
        date sales
0 2016-12-24     5
1 2016-12-25     2
2 2016-12-26     0
3 2016-12-27     4
4 2016-12-28     0
5 2016-12-29     0
6 2016-12-30     0
7 2016-12-31     8
```

Last if need change format:

```
df.date = df.date.dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
print (df)
       date sales
0  20161224     5
1  20161225     2
2  20161226     0
3  20161227     4
4  20161228     0
5  20161229     0
6  20161230     0
7  20161231     8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael